# An integral resulting from perturbation theory

Tags: calculus, integration, mathematical-physics

After a calculation with perturbation theory in a many-body problem, I end up with the following integral which I cannot compute:

$$I=\int_{-D}^{E}\int_{E}^{D}\int_{-D}^{E} dx_1 dx_2 dx_3 \dfrac{1}{x-x_1+x_2-x_3}$$

It seems simple, but the moment you make a first integral (e.g, with respect to $x_3$), you've got the logarithms to integrate and it gets very messy very quickly, and the integral is undoable.

Another thing I tried is to rewrite the integrand as some other integral and then use Fubini. For instance, it seemed a good idea to use the fact:
$$\dfrac{1}{a}=\text{sign}(a) \int_0^\infty\text{e}^{-\vert a \vert y} dy$$ and write:
$$\int_0^\infty \int_{-D}^{E}\int_{E}^{D}\int_{-D}^{E} dx_1 dx_2 dx_3 dy  \ \text{sign}(x-x_1+x_2-x_3)  \ \text{e}^{-\vert x-x_1+x_2-x_3 \vert y},$$
but, again, the sign-dependence of the limits in the integral (after doing the first one) makes the problem untractable.

I think that something in this line (rewrite the integrand as a different integral and use Fubini) could work, but I would need some representation which is not sign-dependent.

I would like to at least reduce the 3-dimensional integral to a simple 1-dimensional integral (that I could then compute easily numerically)

Thanks!

PS: I add the tag 'mathematical physics' because this is a very typical sort of integrals one finds in feynman diagrams calculations or related things.

Answer (score 0):

It's straightforward to integrate logarithms indefinitely, and more generally integration by parts shows
$$\int x^n \log x \ {\rm d}x = \frac{x^{n+1}}{n+1} \times  \log x - \int \frac{x^{n+1}}{n+1} \times \frac{1}{x} \ {\rm d}x = \frac{x^{n+1} \log x}{n+1} - \frac{x^{n+1}}{(n+1)^2}$$
As far as I can see, this should be all you need to work out the answer. It might be ugly, but it's straightforward!

Comment: I think what the OP meant when he wrote "messy" is that, while the transformations you describe work very well for indefinite integrals, with a definite integral, the limits would have to be substituted after every definite integral evaluation, e.g. if we look at [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2320051/definite-integral-integration-by-parts/2320068#2320068) post and a multitude of similar posts on this site.

Comment: @299792458 The OP specifically said "the integral is undoable", which I take to mean "cannot be expressed with elementary functions", which is not true. Also, it is not necessary to substitute immediately -- if you prefer, compute the $x_1,x_2,x_3$ integrals indefinitely first, giving $J(x,x_1,x_2,x_3)$, then computing e.g. $K(x,x_1,x_2) = J(x,x_1,x_2,E)-J(x,x_1,x_2,-D)$ makes the $x_3$ integral definite, and so on.

Comment: Can this _always_ be done? What if $J$ has a singular point at either of the two limits? Or if it diverges.

Comment: @299792458 The "hard" part of integration is computing the indefinite integral. Any divergences in the indefinite integral when evaluated between the endpoints reflect divergences in the original integral. Note that the original $I$ has no divergences for $x$ sufficiently large compared to $|D|$ and $|E|$; the indefinite integral will have no divergences in this range either. Of course, the original problem is ill-defined if the integrand can be singular (though e.g. a principal value prescription could give it meaning).